# how to find char in column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables

1. table with all country codes like KZ,US,RU
2. table tranzactions with terminal location like 
   (Starbucks 1500 Broadway *Near Times Square US)
   (CoffeBoom KZ Mendekulova district *Near Dostyk plaza)

and I want select
country code number , code str , location terminal name
like

```
398 | KZ | CoffeBoom KZ Mendekulova district *Near Dostyk plaza
840 | US | tarbucks 1500 Broadway *Near Times Square US
```

and without case when in terminal location name has code char in string like `'Gucci Moscow Redkzsuzin district RU'` where char `'KZ','UZ'` country code  I want to select only `'RU'`.

Comment: This question is not very clear. Please provide more sample data and the required output derived from it.

Comment: Please edit the question and show the complete table DDL and sample data in table format. you can make a table here - https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try building a regular expression incorporating column code_str within itself. The following attempts such. It builds an expression looking for the beginning of the string or a space followed the country code followed by a space or end-of-string and extracts rows matching. However, both false positives and false negatives as your searching free form text. Any occurrence matching that pattern will be returned even if NOT actually the a valid code and can miss valid ones as well. For example it will not find the row:

```
982,'US', 'Starbucks 618 Miracle Mile, Chicago, IL, USA'
```

You may need to workout a better definition of what you are searching for.

```
with tranzactions (country_code_number , code_str , location_terminal_name) as  
  (select  398,'KZ', 'CoffeBoom KZ Mendekulova district *Near Dostyk plaza' from dual union all 
   select  840,'US', 'Starbucks 1500 Broadway *Near Times Square US'        from dual union all
   select  982,'US', 'Starbucks 618 Miracle Mile, Chicago, IL, USA'         from dual    
  )
select * from tranzactions
  where regexp_like(location_terminal_name, '(^| )' ||  code_str || '( |$)' );
```